# UITapGestureRecognizer not firing in UITextField

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitextfield, uigesturerecognizer

I have a situation in which I need to distinguish between a user tapping a text field and a text field gaining focus programmatically. In this setting, text fields can gain focus programmatically, or through user interaction. Therefore, textShouldBeginEditing is not appropriate since it is called regardless of whether the event is user interaction or programmatic.

My text fields are in a table view and I am trying to set the gesture recognizers in cellForRowAtIndexPath. Here is my code from cellForRowAtIndexPath:

```
if([cell isKindOfClass:[PPTTextCell class]]){
    UITapGestureRecognizer *textTap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(textTapped:)];
    UITextField* textField = (UITextField*)[self getInputControlFromCell:cell];
    [textField setUserInteractionEnabled:YES];
    [textField.superview addGestureRecognizer:textTap];
}
```

The method `getInputControlFromCell`returns a text field if one exists in the cell. In the same class I have the following:

```
- (void) textTapped:(UITapGestureRecognizer*)tap {
    NSLog(@"text field tappped");
}
```

When tapping the text field, the textTapped method is never fired. What am I missing? Thanks!

Comment: [textField.superview addGestureRecognizer:textTap]; are you sure you really meant that? isn't correct to add gesture right to text field rather than its superview?

Comment: I've tried both ways, neither work. Another post suggesting using the superview

Answer (score 0, accepted):

UITextField does not send touch events, but you can make a subclass and override `pointInside: withEvent:` method.

```
- (BOOL)pointInside:(CGPoint)point withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    NSLog(@"text field tappped");
    return YES;
}
```